How to modify the user group of IIS APPPOOL \ xxx
I created a IIS website, the application pool name is testAppPool.
Then I run the following code in the website, obtain current user group permissions:
 WindowsIdentity winIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

 if (winIdentity == null)
 {
     str += "Cannot get current user identity. Exiting...";
 }
 else
 {
     str += "<br/>Current user name:\t" + winIdentity.Name;
     str += "<br/>Current user authentication type:\t" + winIdentity.AuthenticationType;
     str += "<br/>Current user SID:\t" + winIdentity.User;
     str += "<br/>Current user token:\t" + winIdentity.Token;
     str += "<br/>Token owner SID:\t" + winIdentity.Owner;
     str += $"<br/>Current user has {winIdentity.Groups.Count} group memberships.";

     foreach (IdentityReference group in winIdentity.Groups)
     {
         try
         {
             NTAccount ntAcc = (NTAccount)group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
             str += $"<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Group :&nbsp;&nbsp;{ntAcc.Value}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 【SID:&nbsp;{group.Value}】";
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             str += $"<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Group :&nbsp;&nbsp;【SID:&nbsp;{group.Value}】";
         }
     }
 }

I got this result like this:
Current user name: IIS APPPOOL\test
Current user authentication type: Negotiate
Current user SID: S-1-5-82-2084461697-3881244625-4442817516-662440669-514472240
Current user token: 2080
Token owner SID: S-1-5-82-2084461697-3881244625-4442817516-662440669-514472240
Current user has 9 group memberships.
    Group :  Everyone    
    Group :  BUILTIN\Users    
    Group :  NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE    
    Group :  CONSOLE LOGON    
    Group :  NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users   
    Group :  NT AUTHORITY\This Organization   
    Group :  BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS    
    Group :  LOCAL    
    Group :  【SID: S-1-5-82-0】

It contains the user group BUILTIN\Users, and I found that IIS APPPOOL\test can access all disks, read and modify.
How can I remove the IIS APPPOOL\test account from BUILTIN\Users group.
But I found that IIS APPPOOL\test isn't in the Users Group.
The following image link show the Users Group in my computer.
thanks very much.
Image link:
users group

Generally, we will create a new account for the applicationpool and remove it from the Users group like below.



Thank you for your answer, But it doesn't seem to work.

This CustomAppPoolUser is not in the Users group and can still access other disk directories.
